# Google Calendar API for PHP is very large, do need to download all of it?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have to use Googe calendar API for one of my projects but the PHP API library of google calendar is very large when unzip it is around 20MB

so I will like to know do I have to add all of this or there is some small library

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client

Comment: In 2020 what is the issue with a 20mb library?

Comment: I don't want my plugin to be that large

Comment: @rajeshsingh check my new answer

Answer (score 0):

## Question:

> Do I need to download all Google Calendar API?

## Answer:

Yes. You do.
Every class in the API has its dependencies. If you remove pieces of code that are necessary your application will fail.

You could try to manually ["Tree-shake"](https://bitsofco.de/what-is-tree-shaking/) the library, since PHP does not have Tree-shaking capabilities. You could also [minify](https://php-minify.com/) the library in hopes the output is small enough for your needs.
Anyways, I would not worry too much, since PHP doesn't load classes into memory until they are instantiated. This means your unused classes won't be affecting the server, they will just sit on hard storage.